# After new router WLAN doesn't connect anymore

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.04, network-manager

I switched routers from a Fritzbox 7390 to a Dlink 615. Since I switched I cant connect over WLAN in 13.04 to the Dlink. It works fine in Windows8 and my Android devices.

Thanks for yor help :)

```
Jul 31 13:00:59 Netbook NetworkManager[1041]: <warn> (eth1): DHCPv4 request timed out.
Jul 31 13:00:59 Netbook NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (eth1): canceled DHCP     transaction, DHCP client pid 2858
Jul 31 13:00:59 Netbook NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Jul 31 13:00:59 Netbook NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
Jul 31 13:00:59 Netbook NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (eth1): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Jul 31 13:00:59 Netbook NetworkManager[1041]: <warn> Activation (eth1) failed for connection 'Go.Israel1'
Jul 31 13:01:00 Netbook NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
Jul 31 13:01:00 Netbook NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (eth1): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jul 31 13:01:00 Netbook NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (eth1): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Jul 31 13:01:00 Netbook avahi-daemon[1001]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::762f:68ff:fea8:48c0 on eth1.
Jul 31 13:01:00 Netbook avahi-daemon[1001]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv6 with address fe80::762f:68ff:fea8:48c0.
Jul 31 13:01:00 Netbook avahi-daemon[1001]: Interface eth1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jul 31 13:01:00 Netbook kernel: [  165.295392] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Jul 31 13:01:00 Netbook kernel: [  165.303768] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Jul 31 13:01:00 Netbook kernel: [  165.303778] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Jul 31 13:01:00 Netbook kernel: [  165.303783] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 31 13:01:00 Netbook kernel: [  165.303787] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 31 13:01:00 Netbook kernel: [  165.303790] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 31 13:01:00 Netbook kernel: [  165.303793] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 31 13:01:00 Netbook kernel: [  165.303797] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 31 13:01:00 Netbook wpa_supplicant[1230]: eth1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=0
Jul 31 13:01:00 Netbook NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (eth1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected</$>
```

Comment: Which WLAN are you using? What is the output of `sudo modprobe wl`?

Comment: markjh@Netbook:~$ sudo modprobe wl
[sudo] password for markjh: 
markjh@Netbook:~$                                                           There is no output ? All I did, was switching my Router :(

Answer (score 0):

Install the proprietary wifi drivers for your computer. wl is a module in the Broadcom drivers, so it's absence means you are not using them. Chances are, your router is incompatible with the open-source drivers. That would explain why Windows and Android work, but Linux does not.